# Using Histograms for Discrete Data?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the following

[image]

From my previous understanding, Histograms were used only to model continuous data. However, here the histogram is used to model the number of incorrect notes, which is clearly discrete. Hence, I suspect that Histograms can be used to model discrete data.

Let's say we can model discrete data with a Histogram. I see many immediate problems. To ensure, the bars are touching we must extend the classes such that $1-5$ becomes $0.5-5.5$. Hence it seems that when we do model discrete data, we more or less treat the data as being continuous in nature. It obviously doesn't make sense to have half a note.

So what is going on here?

Comment: Histograms do not model data, but they display data, with the area in each bar indicating how many or how frequent that range of values is seen. In the counting case, it is reasonable to say the interval $[0,5,5.5)$ covers the potential values $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and if you were trying to get an approximation to the overall mean, it could be reasonable to take the midpoint of the interval as $3$; similarly with the $11-20$ range and the interval $[10.5,20.)5$ to take the midpoint as $15.5$ even though this is not a possible count integer value

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaking *frequency table intervals* for *histogram buckets/bins*. If the data is discrete, the frequency table will show it. However, when constructing a histogram one needs create buckets/bins/intervals that are for continuous data.

Note that the intervals in your frequency table given are not of equal size. This could lead to confusion: Area or Height e.g. the last interval (41 - 70) has height 18 but area $18\cdot 29$ while the 3rd interval (11 - 20) has height 26 and area $26 \cdot 9$ and we see that $26 > 18$ but $26 \cdot 9 < 18 \cdot 29$.